# Estoy creando una función para acualizar datos, hasta el momento llevo esto... pero el test de actualizar popularity no pasa

Tags: javascript, funciones, test, testing, actualizacion

// Actualiza la propiedad  del accesorio,
// Para eso deberás comprobar cuantos gatos visten el accesorio recibido por parámetros (es un id)
// Si la cantidad de gatos que visten el accesorio son 2, entonces la popularidad del accesorio debe valer 'average'
// Si la cantidad de gatos que visten el accesorio son 3 (o mas), entonces la popularidad del accesorio debe valer 'high'
// Si se actualizó la popularidad del accesorio, devolver un mensaje que diga 'La popularidad del accesorio <color_accesorio> <tipo_accesorio> fue actualizada a '
// Si no se actualizó la popularidad del accesorio, devolver un mensaje que diga 'No hubieron cambios en la popularidad del accesorio <color_accesorio> <tipo_accesorio>'
// Si el id de accesorio no existe arrojar un Error ('accesorio no encontrado' y no actualiza la popularidad)
// Buscar el accesorio en la lista de accesorios

```
updateAccessoryPopularity: function (accessoryId) {
    let accessory = accessories.find(acc => acc.id === accessoryId);
    if (!accessory) {
    throw new Error('accesorio no encontrado');
    }

    let numCatsUsingAccessory = cats.filter(cat => cat.accessories.includes(accessoryId)).length;
    let newPopularity;
    if (numCatsUsingAccessory === 2) {
      newPopularity = 'average';
    } else if (numCatsUsingAccessory >= 3) {
      newPopularity = 'high';
    } else {
      return `No hubieron cambios en la popularidad del accesorio ${accessory.color} ${accessory.type}`;
    }
    if (accessory.popularity === newPopularity) {
      return `La popularidad del accesorio ${accessory.color} ${accessory.type} fue actualizada a ${newPopularity}`
    }
    accessory.popularity = newPopularity;
```

}